# htaccess RewriteRule along with parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How should I write in htaccess file to rewrite

http://mySite/index.php?id=55 
as http://mySite/55 ??

55 is just an example, but it will vary on each id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 1):

In htaccess in the document root

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^([^./]+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This will allow you to access "/index.php?id=numbr" using "/number" .